# Does open xml sdk 2.0 support linux platform or not?

Tags: linux, openxml-sdk

I want to know Whether OPENXML SDK provide support for linux platform or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Supported Operating Systems:Windows 7;Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2;Windows Server 2008 R2;Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2;Windows Vista Service Pack 2;Windows XP Service Pack 3

It MIGHT run under mono but I really doubt it. It depends on .Net 3.5 and `System.IO.Packaging` which has a partial implementation in mono.